# Convert Array of Either<E,A> to Either<E,A[]> (sequence function in Scalaz)

Tags: functional-programming, fp-ts

I am still learning and playing with fp-ts and can't figure this out.

I have an array of `Either<any, number>[]` and I would like to get an `Either<any, number[]>`.

I have looked at `Apply.sequenceT` and the example sequenceToOption and it looks close.

```js
import { NumberFromString } from 'io-ts-types/lib/NumberFromString'
import { Either } from 'fp-ts/lib/Either'

const a:Either<any,number>[] = ['1','2','3'].map(NumberFromString.decode)

console.log(a)
// [ { _tag: 'Right', right: 1 },
//   { _tag: 'Right', right: 2 },
//   { _tag: 'Right', right: 3 } ]
```

I want instead either an error or array of numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To go from `Array<Either<L, A>>` to `Either<L, Array<A>>` you can use `sequence`:

```js
import { array } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array'
import { either } from 'fp-ts/lib/Either'

array.sequence(either)(arrayOfEithers)
```

Your example can also be further simplified using `traverse`

```js
array.traverse(either)(['1','2','3'], NumberFromString.decode)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using io-ts I would recommend adding your array to the decoder like so:

```
import { NumberFromString } from 'io-ts-types/lib/NumberFromString'
import * as t from 'io-ts'

const { decode } = t.array(NumberFromString)

const resultA = decode(['1','2','3']);
const resultB = decode(['1','2','junk']);

console.log(resultA) // { _tag: 'Right', right: [1, 2, 3] }
console.log(resultB) // { _tag: 'Left', left: <ERRORS> }
```

Otherwise the answer from Giovanni should be fine.